# How would you name this peculiar finger position?

Tags: expressions

Say if by gripping a pen, the thumb is placed on top of other fingers (the index finger in the example below), instead of touching the pen itself, how would you name that position? A short expression with as few words as possible is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [thumb wrap](https://theanonymousot.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/thumb-wrap-thumb-tuck.jpg?w=768&h=614) according to these experts.

Comment: I changed it. Just for my own info, did you downvote me for that?? :)

Comment: No, it wasn't me.  I just upvoted you for the correction  :)

Comment: @PeterKämpf Bear in mind, there is nothing "official" about it. Seems to be the same picture as the one you posted. Somebody is ripping off pictures, wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: @Lambie: No, I made the picture myself; both are similar but use a different pen and a different hand ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like:

> someone holding a pen in his **fist**.

It's not entirely accurate, and also implies a *tight grip*, but does convey that it *looks* awkward.